# Disable Floating when using Telerik Rad Dock control (Silverlight)

Tags: .net, silverlight, telerik

I am trying to implement the Telerik Rad Docking control.

I want to force it so that items can never be floating windows. They should always be docked.

We should be able to move them between docks, but if you drop it out of a dock zone, it should return back to it's previous position automatically.

I've been looking at the PaneStateChange event and it's OriginalSource property in the event args, but can't find find a way to check if the Pane is over a dockable hotspot or not.

I'm not sure if the above event is actually fired both when it is first "picked up" and when it is dropped.

Sorry if my question seems a little vague.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find an exact answer to what I was looking for.

However, we were saving the location of docked items, and just wrote some code to dock any floating windows to their nearest compass point before saving the layout configuration.

Comment: Awesome, if you want to share the code for your implementation we can include it in our knowledge base articles to help future folks who encounter this scenario!

Answer (score 2):

I've been searching for an answer to this question for several days myself.  I ended up finding the answer in the documentation:

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/dock-getting-started.html

Setting the property DockMode="Docked" in the RadControl enforces the behavior that the RadDock must end up in an *Allowed* , or Non-*Forbidden* RadZones.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this same functionality and as of Q1 2013 it exists. It took me a while to find it in the Telerik documentation so I thought I'd save others the hassle:

> With the official Q1 2013 release of UI for WPF [AND SILVERLIGHT] we introduced a new DragDrop mode for the Docking control which enables dragging and dropping panes without being able to leave them floating.

This behavior can be turned on with the new DragDropMode property which is of Enum type and can be set to any of the following values:

Immediate - the default DragDrop behavior.

Deferred - provides a completely different way of handling the drag and drop inside RadDocking. With it you can forbid floating of panes and at the same time allow dragging them.

NOTE: When deferred the panel can be made floating only through the ContextMenu (hide this if you don't want to enable it at all)